# No Internet after static IP Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, internet, dhcp

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 Server, and one to an other day i dosn't become from the router a dhcp adress, but when i set a static ip adress i can connect localy to the services on the server, but I can not get a connection to the internet.

I have tried to set who I described above, to set a static IP (I did this in Netplan, but wenn i have tried to execute "netplan apply" or "netplan try" the error is netplan are not installed ), after the I can connact localy to the IP but can not reach for example google with a ping. Have someone a Idea why this happens?

Comment: If your DHCP server (often your router) stops properly issuing IP addresses, then try restarting or investigating that DHCP server.

Comment: Does your router issue an internal static IP addressing ? If so, you don't need to re-set it, it creates a conflict